Are there any archives that I could use to do "apt full-upgrade" on Rasbian Jessie or Stretch?
I have an old Raspberry P B+ which used run much faster with the old versions of Rasbian.  I can still find the install images for Rasbian Jessie or Stretch, but the repositories needed to do apt update or apt full-upgrade are no longer available.  I could not find them in any of the usual locations or on the Wayback machine.  Is there any way to do those updates today?  Will it eventually become impossible to update Buster, Bullseye, or Bookworm?

NOTE there has NEVER been a "Rasbian"

These have been archived and will NEVER have updates but can still be used.
Stretch was archived on 17-Aug-2023 and Buster will soon follow.
Any references to archive.raspbian.org mirrordirector.raspbian.org or raspbian.raspberrypi.org should be replaced with legacy.raspbian.org
E.g. for Stretch /etc/apt/sources.list should contain
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
NOTE the latest image files can still be downloaded from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/
NOTE https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/ contains all downloads.

Thank you Milliways, it works!  Using legacy.raspbian.org solves the problem.  And I promise to spell Raspbian correctly from now on.

@Seamus it is (or has been) documented but the Raspberry Pi Ltd. approach to documentation seems to be to delete everything older than the current OS.

@Seamus There are regular announcements on legacy materials moving from archive.raspbian.org to legacy.raspbian.org
